# Replacing items within a string

Tags: javascript

I currently have this general error message in my script, which I would like to replace with more specific details.

```
errorMessage: "Your selected file, {{fileName}}, is not a proper format of {{formats}}"
```

I would like to replace `fileName` with the name of the file they selected.

This is what I have working so far:

```
validateError(
   errorMessage.replace(/{{formats}}/, formatArray)
);
```

So I tried this:

```
validateError(
       errorMessage.replace(/{{formats}}/, formatArray),
       errorMessage.replace(/{{fileName}}/, inputFile.name)
    );
```

when I run this the {{fileName}} appears this way and is not replaced by the file name. The `inputFile` is a declared variable that already has the file data info so I know that the name does exist.

What am I doing wrong or overlooking?

Comment: What does the inputFile.name print when using `console.log(inputFile.name)`?

Comment: @AhmadHosny the actual name of the file. example: starsInSky.doc - i wonder if it has to do with having two replace statements in one method

Comment: Are you missing a right parenthesis at the end of the first replace?

Comment: Are you able to use ES6 either native or through a transpiler? If so it has such things [built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @AhmadHosny no that was my mistake typing it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.replace` function doesn't mutate the string (strings in JavaScript are immutable), but returns a new string. Therefore, you can either save the result to a variable or chain `.replace` calls. Also, since you are using regex, I recommend escaping the `{`, since it is a special character, or just using a `string` instead.

Saving to a variable (using a string instead of regex):

```
var formatReplaced = errorMessage.replace('{{formats}}', formatArray);
validateError(formatReplaced.replace('{{fileName}}', inputFile.name));
```

Or chaining `.replace` calls (escaping special regex characters):

```
validateError(errorMessage.replace(/\{\{formats\}\}/, formatArray).replace(/\{\{fileName\}\}/, inputFile.name));
```

I would also recommend giving your variables better names. When reading `formatArray`, I assumed it was an array until you mentioned that it worked with the replace function. I'd recommend something like `userFormat`.

Comment: for some reason i am still not getting the `{{fileName}}` to be replaced. It just shows up on the page as `{{fileName}}`

Comment: I have no idea what could be happening. The code works when testing in the browser console. Could you edit your post with more of the code you're using? Thank you!

Comment: Got it working! I was out of order with my `(` which is weird because it didn't complain when i build. Thanks so much!